# Should I normalize training and test test separately after shuffling and splitting?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I want to normalize my data in the range [0,1]. Should I normalize data after shuffling and splitting?Should I repeat the same procedure for test test? I came across a python code which was using such type of normalization. Is this the correct way to normalize data with target range [0,1]

```
`X_train = np.array([[ 1., -1.,  2.], [ 2.,  0.,  0.],[ 0.,  1., -1.]])
a= X_train
for i in range(3):
    old_range = np.amax(a[:,i]) - np.amin(a[:,i])
    new_range = 1 - 0
    f = ((a[:,i] - np.amin(a[:,i])) / old_range)*new_range + 0
    lis.append(f)
b = np.transpose(np.array(lis))
print(b)`
```

Here is my result after normalization.

```
`[[0.5, 0., 1.]
[1., 0.5, 0.33333333]
[0., 1., 0.]]`
```

Comment: Yes you have to do the same to the test set. From the result above, the algorithm works well. However, you can use `scikit-learn` package for data processing s.t. you don't code from scratch.

Comment: So now I will pick minimum and maximum value from each column of the test set? or should I use the same  min and max value(each column) that I used in train set ?

Comment: I also want to make sure that should I perform this normalization after shuffling the data? or before shuffling for each class separately?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Should I normalize data after shuffling and splitting?

Yes. Otherwise, you are leaking information from the future (i.e., test here). More information [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174823/how-to-apply-standardization-normalization-to-train-and-testset-if-prediction-i); it is for standardization, and not normalization, (and R, not Python) but the arguments are equally applicable.

> Should I repeat the same procedure for test?

Yes. Using the scaler that was fitted to the training dataset. In this case, it means using the max and min from the training dataset for scaling the test dataset. This ensures consistency with the transformation performed on the training data and makes it possible to evaluate if the model can generalize well.

You do not have to code it from scratch. Using [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing

X_train = np.array([[ 1., -1.,  2.], [ 2.,  0.,  0.],[ 0.,  1., -1.]])
X_test = np.array([[ 0, -1.,  1.5], [ 2.5,  0.,  1]])

scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
scaler = scaler.fit(X_train)

X_train_minmax = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test_minmax = scaler.transform(X_test)
```

*Note*: for most applications, standardization is the recommended approach for scaling `preprocessing.StandardScaler()`

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by this sentence? "Using the scaler that was fitted to the training dataset."

Comment: Added. Answered your question?